# Using Offset/Fetch for multiple Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to use Offset/Fetch for multiple rows.

This is what I have:

| Name |
| --- |
| Jack |
| Daniel |
| Christian |

And this is what I want:

| Name1 | Name2 | Name3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | Daniel | Christian |

With Offset and Fetch, I am only able to select a single row, but not all in a row.

```
SELECT
    s1.Name
FROM
    SystemInDetail SiD
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Systems1 ON s1.ID = SiD.ID
WHERE
    SiD.Number = 'XYZ'
ORDER BY
    s1.Name
OFFSET
    0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Now I only get "Jack", but I would like to join it and read "Daniel" and "Christian" as well in a single row.
But as far as I see Im not able to use a left join after using OFFSET.

Thanks!

Comment: which database system are you using, also look for dynamic pivot and your database system

Comment: Im using Microsoft SQL Server Standard

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query

Comment: I tried it, but doesnt work in my case unfortunately.

Comment: then show your try, also there are multiple versions, you should test more

Comment: Offset is for paging, you probably want PIVOT. there *might* be a pivot question already asked here on stackoverflow

Comment: Seems you need to pivot/conditionally aggregate on the value of `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: @siggemannen - just a couple https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+pivot

Comment: Hah, i thought there would be more @MartinSmith! Someone should write a pivot code generator and cash out

Comment: Do I always need a sum when using pivot?

Comment: No - for string columns you would need to use `MIN`/`MAX`

Comment: And how can I select the first, second , third... row with MIN/MAX? I cant find anything.

Comment: You need to use `ROW_NUMBER` as Thom A suggests. This has been answered many times. Start here https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bsql-server%5d%20pivot%20ROW_NUMBER%20&searchOn=3

Comment: @MartinSmith Any examples?

Comment: I guess I need to write a new question, because based on the link above I dont get a result which is useful for me.

Comment: You keep writing that, but you don't include the sql you actually write. Better improve your current one. For example, why do you need first second third, if you just have 3 rows. Do you perhaps have say 10 rows in reality, which you want to split "per three"?

Comment: No I have up to 8 rows which should all be selected into one row, and I thought there is a way to achieve this with using offet and fetch, but apparently this is not possible and now I have to use a mix of pivot and MIX/MAN and I dont have a query for that currently.

Comment: so you want 8 columns from 8 rows? how do you know which row gets into which column?

Comment: Row 1 => Column 1, Row 2 => Column 2 and so one

Comment: @Boby will it work if all row data will be come in a single column with comma separated value?

Comment: I think that would be ok yes!

Comment: In that case, you might want to look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

Sample data:

```sql
create table sampletable (somevalue nvarchar(100), id int)
insert into sampletable
select 'A' as someValue, 1 as id
        union all
        select 'B', 2 as id
        UNION ALL
        select 'C', 4 as id
        union all
        select 'D', 3 as id
        union all
        select 'E', 5 as id
        union all
        select 'F', 6 as id
        union all
        select 'G', 8 as id
        union all
        select 'H', 7 as id
```

Script:

```sql
select max(case when sort = 1 THEN someValue END) AS col1
,   max(case when sort = 2 THEN someValue END) AS col2
,   max(case when sort = 3 THEN someValue END) AS col3
,   max(case when sort = 4 THEN someValue END) AS col4
,   max(case when sort = 5 THEN someValue END) AS col5
,   max(case when sort = 6 THEN someValue END) AS col6
,   max(case when sort = 7 THEN someValue END) AS col7
,   max(case when sort = 8 THEN someValue END) AS col8
from (
    select row_number() over(order by id) AS sort, *
    from sampletable x
    ) x
```

Output:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 | col8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | D | C | E | F | H | G |

The concept of pivot is simple: you need to know which row is 1, 2, 3 and then you can aggregate on it by using conditional aggregation.

`row_number() over(order by id)` - this part figures out which row is which. SQL Server has no concept of inherit sort or row number, so you must specify it explicitely, or you risk running into issues where sort changes. Here, i use sort by id, but you probably have some other sorting criteria. If you have none, then you have to figure out one.

`max(case when sort = 1 THEN someValue END)` - this is the conditional aggregation. It creates a column for every sort id where sort matches the desired value ie. 1, 2, 3. If case is not true, then it returns NULL, which is always sorted last in MAX.